# BackPack for Laravel and number in editable columns. Localization in Czech repuplic. We use a comma instead of a decimal point

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-backpack, laravel-backpack-5

I managed to talk Backpack into replacing the decimal point with a comma:
config\backpack\base.php

```
'number_format' => [
        // 'decimals'           => 2,
        'decimal_separator'  => ',',
        'thousands_separator'=> ' ',
    ],
```

But editable-columns ignore it.

I can't imagine how to achieve this for an editable column of type 'type' => 'editable_text'.

Can you advise me please? Thx

Comment: Correct - EditableColumns `editable_text` column doesn't have the same `number_format` as the `number` field. But I see where that could be useful. I've asked my team to take a look at that and provide a PR - should be a quick one.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for bringing this up. Good suggestion!

We took your concern into account and already created a Feature Request to implement a solution.

You can follow it here: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/editable-columns/issues/76.

Cheers!

Comment: Actually heads-up Ladislav, that repo is closed-source, so you'll see a 404.

Comment: So how do I know the current status of the problem resolution?